# I want to display the order date and time the format of time should be 10:30pm 9th April

Tags: date, magento, time, magento-1.9

I am new in magento can you please suggest me

I want to display the order date and time in this format :  `10:30pm 9th April`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity well you could use Magento's date function is you want to bother. Or you could do it with PHP's date function which works pretty well.

Comment: @JulienLachal - You could, but the OP hasn't come with a programming problem to solve. If there is a programming solution that's great, but it's the question that counts.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was just pointing out that Magento wasn't the issue here. On Magento SE we'd just tell him it's not a Magento-related issue ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want without year like **`12:00 AM 9th September`** then

```
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
echo $time = date('h:i A', strtotime($date)) . ' ' . date("jS F, ", strtotime($date));
```

If you want with year like **`12:00 AM 9th September, 2016`** then

```
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
echo $time = date('h:i A', strtotime($date)) . ' ' . date("jS F, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have your order object as $order, so you can format it as -

`Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('g:ia jS F', strtotime($order->getCreatedAt()));`

if you want the year then this - `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('g:ia jS F, Y', strtotime($order->getCreatedAt()));`